# data attribute inside foreach not changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm using this time counter and need to show it multiple time based on total of row in the database.

I have this javascript for displaying time counter :

```
$(function(){

    $('.countdown').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        ts = new Date($('.note').data('ts')),
        newYear = true;

        if((new Date()) > ts){
            newYear = false;
        }
        $this.countdown({
            timestamp   : ts,
            callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
                var message = "";
                message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
                $this.next().html(message);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

this is how my table looked :

```
id    |      tgl_close1     |   idrek
1     | 2014-11-25 08:00:00 |      1
2     | 2014-11-26 10:00:00 |      1
3     | 2014-11-26 12:10:00 |      1
```

i multiply the countdown by foreach but all of the counter is always counting time based on the first row `tgl_close1` value and not getting the next row value..

here is my complete code :

```
<?php 
$fetch = mysql_query("select tgl_close1
                      from tba
                      where idrek = 1");

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $tgl_close1[] = date("Y, n-1, j, G, i, s", strtotime($row['tgl_close1']));


}
foreach ($tgl_close1 as $tglclose){
 ?>
<br>
<table border="0"><tr><td>
<div class="countdown" data-ts="<?php echo $tglclose"></div>
<p class="note"></p>    
</td></tr></table>


<?php
}
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('.countdown').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        ts = new Date($('.note').data('ts')),
        newYear = true;

        if((new Date()) > ts){
            newYear = false;
        }
        $this.countdown({
            timestamp   : ts,
            callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
                var message = "";
                message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
                $this.next().html(message);
            }
        });
    });

});



</script>
```

Can some one tell me how to set different value into the `data-ts` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading  `ts = new Date($('.note').data('ts'))`, which will give you first note only.
You need to read the `note` which is next to `countdown` div, change it to below code

`ts = new Date($(this).next('.note').data('ts'))`